# Remote webkit debugging with Android 4.4 WebViews

Tags: android, debugging, webview, webkit, google-chrome-devtools

I'm working on webkit debugger which communicates through webkit debugging protocol. My debugger works with Mobile Chrome. I just do

```
adb forward tcp:9222 localabstract:chrome_devtools_remote
```

then I can connect to *localhost:9222/json* and list available pages and connect to appropriate web sockets through webkit debugging protocol. How can I do the same thing for new Android 4.4 Web Views?
I know how to use chrome to debug android web views. My question is how to use API to connect directly webview's debugging protocol. *localhost:9222/json* is empty, when my web view is open on device.
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's possible to forward the port for a webview but you can't debug, using `chrome://inspect` instead - it's easier and you need no manual port forwarding!

FYI:

adb forward tcp:9222 localabstract:webview_devtools_remote_<process id>

e.g.

```
adb forward tcp:9222 localabstract:webview_devtools_remote_8123
```

open `http://localhost:9222` in your chrome browser shows the message: Please use chrome://inspect